# Can not use same function for two listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create two maps, with two Markers (one marker on each map).

On dragging the marker, its position is updated in the DIV element in the page. And on moving the map, the marker is moved to the center of the map and the DIV element is again updated.

I have created functions to make the respective changes. To identify which marker or map is to be checked or moved, I pass the map or marker variable in the function.

However, the map showing weird behavior. On trying to drag a marker, it gets attached to my mouse pointer and is never dropped on the map and no event is triggered.
Also, moving the map does not do anything.

If I declare the function separately for each marker or map in the form

```
addListener(marker, 'drag', function() { //some code });
```

it works perfectly fine.

Not sure what is going wrong.

Here is the code snippet:

```
//add a listener for the marker movement
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_start, 'drag', handleMarkerDrag(marker_start, 1));
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_end, 'drag', handleMarkerDrag(marker_end, 2));

//add a listener for the map
google.maps.event.addListener(map_start, 'dragend', handleMapDragend(map_start, marker_start, 1));
google.maps.event.addListener(map_end, 'dragend', handleMapDragend(map_end, marker_end, 2));
```

and the functions which handle the events:

```
function handleMarkerDrag(marker, x)
{
    //get the current location of the marker
    var marker_pos = marker.getPosition();
    //convert lat-lang datastructure into individual latitude and longitude
    var lat = marker_pos.lat();
    var lng = marker_pos.lng();
    //now update the content in the html page
    if(x == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("longitude_start").innerHTML = lng+'<input type="hidden" name="longitude_start" value='+lng+'>';
        document.getElementById("latitude_start").innerHTML = lat+'<input type="hidden" name="latitude_start" value='+lat+'>';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("longitude_end").innerHTML = lng+'<input type="hidden" name="longitude_end" value='+lng+'>';
        document.getElementById("latitude_end").innerHTML = lat+'<input type="hidden" name="latitude_end" value='+lat+'>';
    }   
}

function handleMapDragend(map, marker, x)
{
    //get the current location of the marker
    var marker_pos = map.getCenter();
    //set marker to the enter of the map
    marker.setPosition(marker_pos);
    //convert lat-lang datastructure into individual latitude and longitude
    var lat = marker_pos.lat();
    var lng = marker_pos.lng();
    //now update the content in the html page
    if(x == 1)
    {

        document.getElementById("longitude_start").innerHTML = lng+'<input type="hidden" name="longitude_start" value='+lng+'>';
        document.getElementById("latitude_start").innerHTML = lat+'<input type="hidden" name="latitude_start" value='+lat+'>';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("longitude_end").innerHTML = lng+'<input type="hidden" name="longitude_end" value='+lng+'>';
        document.getElementById("latitude_end").innerHTML = lat+'<input type="hidden" name="latitude_end" value='+lat+'>';
    }       
}
```

Comment: Oh, and the marker_start, marker_end, map_start, map_end are all global. I don't think it matters in the above context anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I declare the function separately for each marker or map in the form it works perfectly fine. Not sure what is going wrong.*

The difference is that the first attempt provides a function as argument, but the other attempt(that fails) is a function-call(which will be executed immediately).

Wrap the function-call into an anonymous function:

```
//add a listener for the marker movement
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_start, 'drag', function(){handleMarkerDrag(marker_start, 1);});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_end, 'drag', function(){handleMarkerDrag(marker_end, 2);});

//add a listener for the map
google.maps.event.addListener(map_start, 'dragend', function(){handleMapDragend(map_start, marker_start, 1);});
google.maps.event.addListener(map_end, 'dragend', function(){handleMapDragend(map_end, marker_end, 2);});
```

Comment: Great! It works. And, like you said the function WAS being called once immediately in my failed attempt.
I still don't understand though, why the markers were sticking to the mouse pointer.